# query inside query loop php

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code:

```
include('connectTwo.html');

    $query = "select * from users";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $connectTwo);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo $row['username'];
        $user_id = $row['user_id'];
        $profile = getProfile($user_id);
        echo $profile;

    }

    function getProfile($user_id)
    {
        $query = "select * from info where user_id='$user_id'";
        $result = mysql_query($query, $connectTwo);
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $profile = $row['profile'];
        return $profile;
    }
```

The function doesn't return anything. I know that the query is correct because I move it outside the function and it runs and gives me the value I'm looking for. Please post a comment if you are confused about what I'm asking.

Comment: In a function - `$result = mysql_query($query, $connectTwo);`  What is `$connectTwo`?

Comment: In the top of the script notice the `include('connectTwo.html');`. That file connects to my database and create the `$connectTwo` variable which I use for the queries. The query variables have the queries inside and then I execute them.

Comment: you need to pass the mysql connection string into the function

Comment: @u_mulder well, `$query` is defined in the line before as a string (in both cases) and `$connectTwo` obviously _should_ be a resource.

Comment: I'll give that a try... just a minute...

Comment: Thank you - @fortune! It worked! Thank you so much. So I guess that the function couldn't use the global $connectTwo variable and it had to be passed in. thank you so much. Post an answer and I will vote it best! Thank you again. I have been stuck on this for a couple hours.

Comment: Take a look at the error log file. Most likely either a faulty connection resource or some typo in the column names when accessing the rows.

Answer (score 3):

Try left join:

```
$query = "select a.*,b.profile from users a left join info b on b.user_id=a.user_id";
```

Then you can delete `getProfile()` function.

If you still want to use `function getProfile($user_id)`, `global $connectTwo` in it otherwise you cant use it as it is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You can try 2 methods:

Pass the database connection string as an argument to the `function getProfile()`

Like : `getProfile($user_id, $connectTwo);`

OR you can use `global` keyword to use the connection string inside function getProfile()

```
function getProfile($user_id) {
   global $connectTwo;
```

But above all the better approach has been pointed out by @zairwolf in the previous answer.

> Note: Try to use mysqli_* or pdo * functions instead of mysql_*
>   functions.